# using square root function (sqrt) with doubles in OpenCL

Tags: opencl

I've got a kernel which uses the OpenCL builtin square root function (sqrt) but when I try to run the kernel on the GPU I get a unrecognized command error when building, it works fine if i use floats but when using doubles it does not work. I'm running on a Mac OS X 10.7.5 and my Graphics Card is a ATI Radeon HD 6750 card.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Depending on your OpenCL version (in particular on CL 1.1 and below) you may need a `#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION
cl_khr_fp64 : enable` in your kernel before using any `double`s.

Comment: Even adding that extension at the top of my kernel file doesn't make a difference I still get the following build error Undeclared function '_Z9__cl_sqrtd' called by function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently your gpu doesn't support double precision floats:
http://clbenchmark.com/device-environment.jsp?config=12011396

AMD cards that do support double report extension: cl_khr_fp64 (or cl_amd_fp64).

You could check at openCL compile time this way:

```
#ifdef cl_khr_fp64
    #pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable
#elif defined(cl_amd_fp64)
    #pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_amd_fp64 : enable
#else
    #error "Double precision floating point not supported by OpenCL implementation."
#endif
```

Or you could check without running the opencl compile this way:

```
status = clGetDeviceInfo (oclInfo->device, CL_DEVICE_DOUBLE_FP_CONFIG, sizeof configFp64, &configFp64, NULL);
```

Comment: Wow, would have never thought a card of that generation to not have double precision support. I thought that was mandatory for DX11/GL4. But Wikipedia agrees with you, too.